# Python Client sending JSON via REST to Java server

Tags: java, python, json, rest

I am writing a python client to send a json message to a java server. I think the problem is in the client.  Any suggestions? Here is what I have. Python client is first Java Server is second.

```
import json 
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'http://localhost:8080'

json_input = {'sender': 'jdog', 'receiver': 'pacman', 'message': 'awesome!'}

data = json.dumps(json_input)
data = data.encode('utf-8') 

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

r = urllib.request.Request(url, data,headers=headers, method='PUT')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(r)
print(r.info().headers)
print(r.read())
```

The Java server looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class JavaServer {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


String fromclient;

ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (8080);

System.out.println ("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 8080");
Socket connected = Server.accept();
System.out.println( " THE CLIENT"+" "+ connected.getInetAddress() +":"+connected.getPort()+" IS CONNECTED ");

BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));

fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
System.out.println( "RECIEVED:" + fromclient );
connected.close();
}}
```

Comment: you asked *two* questions.

Comment: also, I am using Python 3.4 - most examples are using earlier non compatible versions of Python